# Flash Player (e.g. plugin) crashes when play a video?

Tags: browser, flash, hardware-acceleration

Not sure where to put this, but Chrome, Firefox and IE crashes (the flash player) when I try to watch a video like on youtube.

The screen goes green then a few seconds later it freezes.

Same goes for all 3 of my OS installations. Win 7, Win 7 and Linux Mint. However on my Laptop (I assume same version etc as I've reinstalled to latest on my PC) it works fine. Not sure what is going on here?

on "info" via Chrome I got this from the player

640x360, 648 average kbps, 100% volume
HTTP, 906 kbps
10 stage fps, 29 video fps, 0 dropped, 0 kbps
software video rendering, accelerated video decoding
NaN db, 1 audio factor

Only thing I can think of is the hardware accelerator corrupts the video, because maybe something wrong with my GPUs? (Crossfire).

Thanks

Comment: Is this the same video or does it happen with all/any flash videos?

Comment: All videos, on several sites which actually uses 'video playback' the flash embeds without video (e.g. the flash testing page to make sure its installed, doesn't crash)

Comment: I just booted from a USB stick into Linux Mint and videos work on here. But not the installed OSs. So I'm reinstalling Linux Mint (I need to do that anyway) and then try that. Then got to figure out what wrong with the Windows 7 installations :/ The latest thing I done on the pc is on Linux Mint I installed latest drivers via the .run file which ATI provides.

Comment: Hmm, so you updated the video drivers in Mint (I assume this is a mult-boot system so the exact same hardware) and then the problem started happening?

Comment: I doubt its a virus since Linux Mint (installed one) doesn't work either, and viruses which work on both, at same time. I would say thats very rare.

Comment: Possibly, I didn't go on videos for a while, about ~6 hours after installed latest drivers in Mint I went on youtube and had problems (in Win7) then I switched the OS and same problem

Comment: I had the same problem, green screen, not crash. I was specifically going for a 64bit install (both actually) of the flash. First install, many flash locations green screened but Not ALL.  I retracted my "image" installed again the same way (it does not get any more consistant than that) The second install no green screen, makes Zero sence.  Once I got it going, i locked it down with another backup, and it retained its ability.  Weird stuff, but i am pretty sure it is some sort of software fluke.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do a full uninstall of the Flash player on your windows machines using a tool like Revouninstaller to remove even the bits that are normally left behind. You'll need to remove both the versions for IE and FF/Chrome as they're technically different programs on your computer.

Then clean your temp files completely using a tool like CCleaner.

Then make sure you at least have the critical updates from the OS and the current versions of the browsers. It probably won't hurt to check for updates for your video card and sound card at this time.

Then install the player again and test.

**UPDATE:**

Sounds like the video drivers may have updated stuff on the graphics cards themselves, kinda like a BIOS update, and the systems with older drivers may no longer be completely compatible with the new firmware. Have you updated the drives on all your OSes?

Comment: Just reinstalled Mint, works on here now. (Mint was messed up anyway). Now I'm going to do what you said for Windows. I'll get back to you with the result.

Comment: Try just the video drivers and simple flash uninstall/reinstall first. If that doesn't work try the longer process described above. All the tools I suggest are free or have free versions (which are what I use).

Comment: Both my win7 has different versions (older one works with Crossfire so I can play games :P) but on this one I just uninstalled drivers, (and used driver sweeper) and it works. Now I just have to install drivers again and hope it works afterwards. Thanks for all your help, hope I get drivers and videos to work again together :P

Comment: Glad to help. Especially with Flash and HTML 5 and modern browsers supporting GPU acceleration of advanced web content there's one more thing to troubleshoot in web situations like this.

Comment: Installed latest drivers, green screen again! Turned off hardware acceleration, fixed. Although not sure having it off with be a big negative.. at least it works. Thanks btw.

Answer (score 0):

installed updated radeon drivers and that fixed my problem.